# How to remove "Make sure dartdoc successfully runs on your package's source files."

Tags: flutter, dart, package, dartdoc

I published a Flutter package to https://pub.dev/ and find this message (shown in the screenshot). What do I have to do to solve this?

This should be related to `dartdoc`, but I am not sure how much info I have to add.
I also assume it is hard to make small changes and publish many times to test because I have to update the version and change log every time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Follow instructions on https://dart.dev/tools/dartdoc
Then you can run dartdoc on your machine and check what is go wrong.